# Error when using JSON.NET, only in a  WP7 project

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7, json.net

Here is some code that only fails (it compiles) when used in a WP7 project.

```
            var tree = JObject.Parse(Json);

        var temp =
            from t in tree.Root["dates"].Children()
            select new Schedule {DateString = (string) t["date_string"]};
```

It is a WP7.1 project and the JSON.NET dll I am using is:

...\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.4.0.5\lib\sl4-windowsphone71\Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Here is the exception I find inside temp:

```
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Test.Models.Schedule>' does not contain a definition for 'System' and no extension method 'System' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Test.Models.Schedule>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The "var tree = JObject.Parse(Json);" line parses the json string and builds the tree with no problems.

The exact code runs perfectly in a Monodroid and C# library project (with appropriate JSON.NET builds).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down - I spent an hour googling the error and various JSON.NET posts.  I tried a number of variations and even in other project types as stated above.  If I missed something obvious please point out why in comments not just down vote.

Comment: Have you got `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code?

Comment: @keyboardP yes.  Here are my includes: using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Test.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

Comment: I'm not familiar with `JSON.NET` but is there a chance that a namespace collision is occurring? It seems that `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` has its own form of `Linq`. What happens if you remove `System.Linq`?

Comment: @keyboardP - There is no namespace collision, JSON.NET depends on system.linq.

Comment: The SL4 version of JSON.NET is highly unstable. Try use the SL-3 version (also found in the nuget folder).

Comment: @ClausJørgensen Just tried that but unfortunately have the same problem.  It does seem to be specific to the wp7 build of JSON.NET since it works fine with the other JSON.NET builds.

Answer (score 0):

In my WP7 application I used the following code to read JSON:

```
JsonTextReader jtr;
jtr = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(e.Result));
```

Perhaps that will work?

Comment: I don't think that would work in my case because I need a tree to Linq over and JsonTextReader is a non-cached forward only reader